# How to margin div inside other div?

Tags: html, css, styling

html body,simple form with table and two divs inside(login and table):

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form>
            <div class="login">
                <div class="table">
                    <table class="userInput">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username"
                                name="login"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

My css:

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

table.userInput {
    margin-top: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div#container {
    background: pink;
    height: 100%;
}

div.login {
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 10%;
    width: 10%;
    padding: 10px;
}

div.table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Need my `div class="table"` after `margin-top:15%` of `table class="userInput"` visible with grey background but after offset i can see black color of login `div class="login"`. How to make it grey with margin-top?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand your question well i suggest you to change

```
padding:10px;
```

to

```
padding-top:10px;
```

and increase **width** of `<div class='login'>` element

**EDIT**

Your image change almost everything , please check this fiddle :
[SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/7j8z3v3w/3/)

Only thing i change is remove `margin-top:15%;` and replace it with `padding-top:15%;` so i can add `background-color:grey;` to `table.userInput` element.

Looks like in your image. Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: No problem , happy programing :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `margin-top: 15%;` to `padding-top: 15%;`

```
table.userInput {
    padding-top: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Based on your picture I think this is what you want.

[image: top padding]

http://jsfiddle.net/7j8z3v3w/

Comment: i need that space after margin-top:10%; visible as grey as it should be after offset inside login div with black background

Comment: @RuslanLomov There is no "margin-top:10%" in your CSS. Does changing the "background-color: black;" to "background-color: grey;" in "div.login" not fix your problem? Your question is really hard to understand what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: i add picture to my question :D